# Unity3d : Access the OnClick parameters of Button in a script

Tags: unity, animation

[image]

I have a button and I have attached another script "`PlaySound`" for this button, which plays audio on button click. As soon as the audio gets completed, I want to stop the animation which I am triggering here in `OnClick` of `Button`. How do I access the `Ellen` gameObject and `0` parameter which I set in the Inspector window (check the picture) in the `PlaySound` script

Answer (score 1):

Create a script with a `public Ellen ellen;` or whatever object you want to access. Then, in the script, check if the audio has finished playing and if it has, use `Animator.SetTrigger(x)`, where x is the stop animation parameter.

To be honest, I would do this all in one script with a function to start the audio that waits till the audio finishes then starts a second function to stop the animation. Then use that instead of Ellen

Answer (score 0):

Internally, OnClick assignments are event subscriptions. On the surface, an event source should not know who is listening, so they are not meant to be accessed. Accessing the subscription list could be possible but it would be a hack that would introduce troublesome design.

For this problem, you need a script to hold a reference to the object `Ellen` and trigger the function for animation when the audio finishes playing. You can do it all where you play the sound, or use a separate class and make use of events or messaging.

You can arrange the flow below according to your design:

```
public class AudioVisualController : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...
    
    // Required if you stop the animation within this script.
    [SerializeField] private Ellen ellen;

    public void PlaySound()
    {
        audio.Play();
        Invoke("OnAudioFinished", audio.Length);
    }

    private void OnAudioFinished()
    {
        // Subscribe to this event from other class to stop animation.
        AudioFinished?.Invoke();
        
        // Or, stop the animation from here.
        ellen.Animator.SetTrigger(1);
    {
        
    ...
}

// If you use event subscription, stop the animation here.
public class SomeManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...
    [SerializeField] private AudioVisualController controller;
    [SerializeField] private Ellen ellen;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        controller.AudioFinished += OnAudioFinished;
    }
    
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        controller.AudioFinished -= OnAudioFinished;
    }
    
    private void OnAudioFinished()
    {
        ellen.Animator.SetTrigger(1);
    {
        
    ...
}
```